# Access to font blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors, iccube, iccube-reporting

I want to display icCube report in my app which is runing on Wildfly server with Angular 1.5 as frontend framework. 
Report is displayed using Javascript code snippet from official docs, but I get few errors related to CORS policy, e.g.:

> Access to Font at 'htp://localhost:8282/icCube/doc/ic3-report/app/lib/open-sans/fonts/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.woff?v=1.1.0' from origin 'htp://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'htp://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to enable CORS Origin Support in icCube.xml(in installation folder), but that didn't helped.

```
  <filter>

            <filter-name>Cross Origin</filter-name>
            <filter-class>crazydev.iccube.server.crossorigin.IcCubeCrossOriginServletFilter</filter-class>

            <init-param>
                <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
                <param-value>*</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
                <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
                <param-value>X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,X-DataSource-Auth</param-value>
            </init-param>

        </filter>
```

How do I enable CORS Origin Support and remove these errors, which step did I miss?

Btw, Google Chrome.

Comment: You need to allow CORS on the 'original' webserver not in icCube that looks as being the one serving this file

Comment: Please edit the question with the actual setting of the section <reportingComponentConfiguration>  in icCube.xml.

Comment: This is actual section of <reportingComponentConfiguration>. I just uncommented this code snippet in icCube.xml
@ic3 Do I use exactly this snippet in my web.xml?